# where to use credentials and signature of paypal into android code for chained payment

Tags: android

I am working on paypal integration on android app it works fine for sandbox account,now i am making it live, i want where to use signature (found from paypal) in my app coding and what else is required to go live and what other permissions are required for chained payment

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: thanks for replay,i just want to know where to use signature credentials in android coding or is it needed or not for chained payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chained Payment in Adaptive now are much more selective and limited and the approval of the application is rely on your business model that evaluates by the App Reviewer team in PayPal.

What do you need to do for Live?

1.Register your app in https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications.

2.Provide as details as much during your app submission. Explain with a sample of a test website.

3.If you wish to use Chained Payment, make sure you tick the Chained Payment box.

When your apps has been approved, you need to replace the Sandbox credentials (username, password, signature) and APP ID in your configuration file.

Comment: But in my app i haven't use these credentials(username,password,signature) anywhere so where to use these credentials.I only sandbox APP ID.

Comment: what credentials you use for Sandbox? can you calrify?

Comment: i only use client id and APP ID in sandbox mode,it was working fine on Sandbox.

Comment: it seems you are using REST API. Can you explain how do you integrate it? are you using any SDK?

Comment: i am using MPL SDK to perform chained Payment and not using paypal with any website.I just want to know where to use username,password and signature in my app.